# MRTK V2 - Toggle-Dot moves outside of constraints

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

**Description** - 
I have a settings panel in my scene which appears if I click the settings button on my toolbar. By repeating this, I noticed one bug → **The dot of all toggled toggles moves further and further**. The dot of an untoggled toggle stays in the right position. Did someone fix that bug in the script `interactable` or did a workaround?
**Screenshot**
[image]

**How to reproduce** - 
I used the toggles that were given by the example package. Place one that is already toggled and one not toggled and start play mode. Activate and deactivate the script `Interactable` on your toggle and you should see this behavior
[image]

**My specs**
Unity 2019.2.8f
MRTK v2.0

**-- Edit --**
Confirmed that this [issue has been fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6241#issuecomment-540245852) in Mrtk v2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report! I will ask one of our UX developers to investigate.

This will be tracked on our GitHub site as issue [#6241](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6241).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with the library.

Since it only happens when you enable and disable the script, it possibly gets the X position on start() and then uses that to change the position of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in the latest MRTK verison (2.1)
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases/tag/v2.1.0

Please try out