# MRTK V2.1 - Toggle does not set dimension to 1 at first call

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I updated to MRTK v2.1 and right now I'm struggling with the toggles from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283654/mrtk-v2-toggle-dot-moves-outside-of-constraints). Don't get me wrong, the issue in the linked post got fixed! But now I'm having a different problem.
**What happens:**
I have a settings panel in my scene and the component `DebugContent.cs` attached to it. Every time I open it, `OnEnable` triggers and sets the state of my toggles according to third parameter of `SetToggleState()`. So lets say that the third parameter is always true → `DiagnosticsSystem.ShowProfiler`, `debugProvider.enabled` and `speechInputHandler.enabled` are true!
 On MRTK v2.0 I had no issues, but now on v2.1 my toggles are not getting toggled by the first time. **I have to open my panel a second time so the toggles are toggled**!

```
//OnEnable in DebugContent.cs
private void OnEnable()
{
    // Set Profiler, Log viewer, Speech Input
    Utils.SetToggleState(profilerTgl, profilerTxt, DiagnosticsSystem.ShowProfiler);
    Utils.SetToggleState(logViewerTgl, logViewTxt, debugProvider.enabled);
    Utils.SetToggleState(speechInputTgl, speechInputTxt, speechInputHandler.enabled);
}

//SetToggleState in Utils.cs
public static void SetToggleState(Interactable comp, TextMesh tm, bool isOn)
{
    Debug.Log("Util >> SetToggleState >> Set toggle → " + comp.gameObject.name +" to → " + isOn + " >> Comp is enable → " + comp.enabled + " and has dimension → " + comp.CurrentDimension);
    if (isOn)
    {
        comp.CurrentDimension = 1;
        tm.text = "On";
    }
    else
    {
        comp.CurrentDimension = 0;
        tm.text = "Off";
    }
    Debug.Log("Util >> SetToggleState >> Toggle set to dimension → " + comp.CurrentDimension);
}
```

**More on:**
The strange part is that the first time I open my panel the text of my toggles shows `On` but my toggle is not toggled. Only if I open my panel the second time the toggle get toggled:
[image]
The output of my `Debug.Log` is also interesting, because the current dimension is every time 0:
*First time:*
`Util >> SetToggleState >> Set toggle → Debug_Tgl to → True >> Comp is enabled → True and has dimension → 0` 
`Util >> SetToggleState >> Toggle set to dimension → 1`
*Second time:*
`Util >> SetToggleState >> Set toggle → Debug_Tgl to → True >> Comp is enabled → True and has dimension → 0`
 `Util >> SetToggleState >> Toggle set to dimension → 1`

I'm using `CurrentDimension`, because `SetDimensionIndex` is now deprecated.
I created a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6745) on github.

Comment: "Catherine may already have a fix for this actually coming out in 2.2" by Julenk on Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see response on the *github* page. As a workaround, call the `Utils.SetToggleState` in both `OnEnable` and `Start. DebugContent` OnEnable is invoked before `Interactable.Awake` which make the problematic